# Adding setOnTouchListener makes OnClickListener no longer working

Tags: android

I have an Activity which implements both OnTouchListener and OnClickListener. If i add both listeners to buttons, i get that OnClickListener doesn't work, i mean onClick() method, implemented in the Activity, doesn't do anything.

I assign those listeners in this way.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button1.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

If i remove the

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(this)
```

then onClick() method starts working.

Comment: post your `OnClick()` code.

Comment: return `false` in your `OnTouchListener()` method.

Comment: have you done any R & D on this or simply you are asking a question.? try to do that before asking why am suggesting that is there are plenty of questions available in stack over flow.
just spend some time on it.

Comment: R & D = ? @Manish Dubey: Thanks Manish, it works. Why do i have to return false?

Comment: @ManishDubey Please post your solution as an answer not a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two listeners that you are setting for the view:

```
onClick()
```

> From View.OnClickListener. This is called when the user either touches
>   the item (when in touch mode), or focuses upon the item with the
>   navigation-keys or trackball and presses the suitable "enter" key or
>   presses down on the trackball.

And

```
onTouch()
```

> From View.OnTouchListener. This is called when the user performs an
>   action qualified as a touch event, including a press, a release, or
>   any movement gesture on the screen (within the bounds of the item).

For `onTouch()`,

> onTouch() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether your listener
>   consumes this event. The important thing is that this event can have
>   multiple actions that follow each other. **So, if you return false when
>   the down action event is received, you indicate that you have not
>   consumed the event and are also not interested in subsequent actions
>   from this event.** Thus, you will not be called for any other actions
>   within the event, such as a finger gesture, or the eventual up action
>   event.

To put it simply, for understanding, returning false avoids the conflict for an onTouch action and onClick listener action.

Something you should go through:
[Input Event Listener Interfaces](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

[..which could have been a part of some Research and D, maybe]

Comment: Thank you. Is there an easy-to-print version of that guide?

Comment: meaning? ctrl+P from that link can help, if i didn't get it wrong :?)